# Preserve timestamp with Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, filemtime

Is there a way of preserving the timestamp when using Paramiko to SFTP files from one server to another similar to the `-p` argument in Linux?

Original file:

```
jim@vm3634:~$ ls -la
-rwxrwx---    1 jim  admin    2214 Mar 30 17:33 compcip.asc
```

Uploaded file:

```
sftp> ls -la
-rwxrwx---    1 no-user  no-group    2214 Mar 30 18:49 compcip.asc
```

The uploaded file needs to have the same timestamp as the original.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Paramiko does not support that.

You have to explicitly call the [`SFTPClient.utime`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.utime) after the upload.

---

Note that [pysftp](https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/) (that internally uses Paramiko) supports preserving the timestamp with its [`pysftp.Connection.put()` method](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#pysftp-connection-put).

You can reuse their implementation (code simplified by me):

```
local_stat = os.stat(localpath)
times = (local_stat.st_atime, local_stat.st_mtime)

sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)

sftp.utime(remotepath, times)
```

---

Similarly for [downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53200800/850848).