# Python: FTPLIB Download files with original modify time

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to write a python script to download files from the FTP server, the below code works for me, but I'm curious is there any way to download the files with the original `modify time` from FTP. Is that is possible with python?

`Example: FileZilla have a feature to download the files with the original date time`

```
with open(fileName,'wb') as write
    def writeData(chunk):
        fwrite.write(chunk)
    ftp_client.retrbinary('RETR {}'.format(downFileName), writeData)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348953/how-can-i-set-the-last-modified-time-of-a-file-from-python

Comment: FileZilla justs sets the timestamp afterwards. See link above to see how you can do the same.

Comment: See [how to get the modified time from FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026709/how-to-get-ftp-files-modify-time-using-python-ftplib)

Answer (score 0):

As @Justin correctly commented, just set the timestamp after the download.

```
remote_path = "/remote/path/foo.txt"
local_path = "/local/path/foo.txt"
timestamp = ftp.voidcmd("MDTM " + remote_path)[4:].strip()
mtime = parser.parse(timestamp)

with open(local_path, "wb") as f:
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + remote_path, f.write)

os.utime(local_path, (mtime.timestamp(), mtime.timestamp()))
```

Some references:

- [How to get FTP file's modify time using Python ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29026709/850848)
- [How can I set the last modified time of a file from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11348953/850848)
- [Python Paramiko SFTP get file along with file timestamp/stat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53200800/850848)
- [How can I set the last modified time of a file from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11348953/850848)

---

Though were you downloading all files in a folder, i would be an overkill to call `MDTM` for each. It that case, you can retrieve the timestamp from the directory listing retrieved using `mlsd` or `dir. See [How to get FTP file's modify time using Python ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29026709/850848).